# Mandrill Validation error: Please enter an array

Tags: python, google-app-engine, mandrill, urlfetch

I'm tyring to use `Mandrill` on `Google App Engine`, with `Python`, and for that I'm using the `urlfetch` module, provided by Google.

The adaptation of the code I'm using for it is the following:

`#The jMessage below was split with the formatting below to make it easier to follow`
`#the real code doesn't have such indentation issues`

```
jMessage =
{
"key": mailchimp_key,
"message": 
    {
    "track_clicks": False,
    "track_opens": True,
    "tags": [],
    "google_analytics_domains": [],
    "html": message_html,
    "subject": "Reset your password",
    "from_name": None,
    "merge_var_map": {},
    "auto_text": False,
    "from_email": from_email,
    "headers": {},
    "google_analytics_campaign": [],
    "merge_vars": [],
    "text": None,
    "global_merge_vars": [],
    "url_strip_qs":False,
    "to":   
            [
                {
                "email": to_email,
                "name": None
                }
            ]
    }
}

headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}

result = urlfetch.fetch(url='https://mandrillapp.com/api/1.0/messages/send.json',\
              headers=headers, payload=json.dumps(jMessage), method=urlfetch.POST)

print result.content
```

The output for that is the following:

```
{"status":"error","code":-2,"name":"ValidationError","message":"Validation error{\"message\":\"Please enter an array\"}"}
```

What exactly is that array it wants? I was unsure on what to do, so I wrapped the "message" key, from the `jMessage`with `[]`, making it a list. Indeed, it stopped complaining about the array, however the output was simply `[]`, and I didn't receive any email.

Comment: have you read this: https://mandrillapp.com/api/docs/messages.JSON.html#method=send?

Comment: Yes, I did, but I'm still not sure what I am missing.

Comment: Can you please let me know, how you resolved the above issue?